# How do I store a datatable on the page to access from my gridview?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datatable

I want to look at a datatable in my gridview's RowDataBound event and check to see if a value in the current gridview column exists in the datatable. I would just create my datatable inside the RowDataBound event, but that would mean for every row of the gridview I'm doing a round-trip to the database and creating a datatable. I would rather just create the datatable first, and then in my RowDataBound event access the datatable. I know how to do this using, say a label or hidden field on the page, but how exactly would I go about storing the datatable on the page (or in a variable) that is accessible from within my gridview's RowDataBound event? Can I somehow pass the datatable as an argument into the RowDataBound function? Seems like I'm missing something super simple here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are server-side containers to use of which the `Items` container could be a perfect choice. You could wrap your DataTable with a property:

```
public DataTable TempData
{
    get
    {
        if ( this.Context.Items["tempdata"] != null )
            return (DataTable)this.Items["tempdata"];
        return null;
    }
    set
    {
         this.Context.Items["tempdata"] = value;
    } 
}
```

Then you access the property:

```
this.TempData = yourdatatable;
```

and retrieve it somewhere

```
DataTable storedTable = this.TempData;
```

Comment: Pretty similar in VB? (that's the syntax I use...)

Comment: Yes, should be pretty similar in VB. VB also supports properties plus you are on the same technology.

Answer (score 2):

Declare your DataTable as a class level variable in your page class.  You can then access it from any method.